# Can I use wake on lan with VMWare ESXi guests?

Tags: vmware-esxi, wake-on-lan

I know that I can start the guests from the vmware management interface (vSphere?). Is wol working for the guests?

Answer (score 4):

I know you can set `ethernet0.wakeOnPkctRcv = "TRUE"` in the VM's .vmx file but I can't say I've tested it myself sorry.

Comment: I have to test this.